# Class Instance throws Internal Server Error 500 (PHP, MYSQLi)

Tags: php, apache, mysqli, internal-server-error

I am having a strange situation.

When a class instance is passed to a method & the class instance has not been set, the server throws a 500 error, instead of catching the error.

*This happends during testing 99% of the time, but I want to make sure a user never sees it for that 1%*

BTW : I have already checked my `.htaccess` and `apache2` files <= they are correct

**What do i need to change in my `php.ini` file or something similar to avoid a `500` error everytime this happens??**

Here is some sample code :

```
<?php

function querysomething ($connection_to_mysql, $query) {
  try {
    $query = $connection_to_mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name=?");
    $query->bind_param("s", $name);
    $execute = $query->execute();
    //etc...
    if (!$execute) {
      throw new Exception ("some error");
    }
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    //some error handling
  }
}

?>
```

**If the `$connection_to_mysql` object is not instantiated, the server throws a `500` error**

**Do I need to check if the `$connection_to_mysql` actually exists everytime prior to query?**

Comment: 500 in this case is usually some runtime error in PHP.  Turn the ini setting `display_errors` on and you should be able to see what the actual error is.

Comment: I have like this (when testing) : `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');` I'm just wondering if this could happen even after I fix the errors. I dont want my users to get a `500`

Comment: then what is the actual error message?

Comment: I'm not near my workspace, but its usually a fatal error with mysqli object not found or someother object not found. When these errors happen because of a typo or database connection not created or whatnot, I handle them right there. I am worried about : *If the database connection is lost and the object is not instantiated, then passed to a function, it will throw the `500`.* I need a way to somehow handle `500` errors (redirect page or anything -- I've tried in `apache` but it doesn't redirect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `set_error_handler`/`set_exception_handler` to display a php fatal error-specific page.

Comment: I did some research & that doesn't handle `(E_ERROR)`s so its advised to use `register_shutdown_functions`. I included an answer with the link below. Thanks for your help, I will write something up with your `set_error_handler/set_exception_handler` and the link below

Answer (score 0):

After doing some additional reading on catching `Fatal Errors`, I can across this : [How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)

Instead of using `set_error_handler` & `set_exception_handler`, to catch all errors and process afterwords use `register_shutdown_functions`.

This would allow you to redirect to a page (ex : 500.php or whatever), log the error, & send an email if desired.